# Ember.js #linkTo not pulling correct property from context for dynamic segment

Tags: ember.js, link-to

The `linkTo helper` is creating `<a>` tags with an href that looks like this.

```
 <a id="ember561 class="ember-view" href="/orgs/<Organization:ember349:17>">
```

The url is actually the string representation of the object. The expected functionality is to link to `/orgs/17` where 17 is the id of the context object.

The context I'm passing to linkTo is a model with an id, I'm sure it has an id because I can print out this.id in the template.

```
  #template
  {{#each orgs}}
    {{#linkTo 'organizations.show' this}} {{this.id}} {{/linkTo}}
  {{/each}}

  #router
  Router.map ->
   @resource 'organizations', path: "/orgs", ->
    @route 'show', path: ":id"
    @route 'new'
```

When I click on the messed up link, it transitions to `'/orgs/<Organization:ember349:17>'` and that page has the correct model set.

I can print `{{id}}` from that template and it is correct.

```
ember.js version = Version: v1.0.0-rc.3-292-gbdffb37
```

Comment: Do you have a `serialize` hook for that route? See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your show route needs to define the model if you're using the default serialize method.
In that case I assume `:organization_id`

```
  Router.map ->
    @resource 'organizations', path: "/orgs", ->
      @route 'show', path: ":organization_id"
      @route 'new'
```